# How to return an image or file using Java web service in Browser

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have written a web service GET using Java. I am passing the name of the object(image) thats present in my S3 bucket. When I run the GET url in the browser, i need to see an image/file from s3 bucket. But, I am only able to return S3 url. Hence this is what i get in Browser. I need to actually display image or the file needs to get downloaded when i call my Java web service in Browser just like how you can download by hitting the S3 object Url in browser. But in our case, this needs to happen via Java web service. How can i do it. Below is what i am trying.

```
`@RequestMapping(value ="/getImage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody     
public URL getImage (String inputfile) 
{ 
      AppLogger.info("BlitlineController:createThumbnail:begin");
      ObtainSignedUrl s3Url = new ObtainSignedUrl();
         URL s3url=  s3Url.getSrcSignedUrl(inputfile);
         return s3url;
 }`
```

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways depending on the availability of the url to the browser.

**Option 1**

Applicable if the browser can access the url of image in S3, and the client side can deal with redirects:

Try to Send the "redirect" so that the browser could understand by itself that this is a redirect (has a special response status). The UI side will understand that  (browsers should do that automatically) and will create an http request directly to S3.

Here is an sample of doing this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getImage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getImage(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
    s3Url = calculateUrl and convert to string (maybe with encoding)
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", s3Url);
    httpServletResponse.setStatus(302);
}
```

**Option 2**

This option is applicable when the s3 bucket is not accessible to the browser.
You should connect to AWS with s3 sdk, get the image and send it.

All in all:

I believe you should prefer the first option.

Comment: Can you please tell me if this can be done without servlet? I am using only Restful web service without servlets..

Comment: I havent talked about servlets. Its possible to pass HttpServletResponse into methods of classes annotated with @RestContoller

Comment: In that case, I did try your solution. However, I didn't get the expected response when I called the endpoint in browser. Below was how my method looked like RequestMapping(value = "/getImage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getImage(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, String filename) {
    s3Url = getSignedUrl(filename);
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", s3Url);
    httpServletResponse.setStatus(302);
}

Comment: What was the response? What did devtools network tab in browser show?